# Verificar se a tela esta desbloqueada service android

Tags: android

Estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo que tem um serviço de `AlarmManager` que chama posteriormente um `Service`. Acontece que quando iniciar o `Service` quero verificar se o celular esta em uso, ou seja, com a tela acessa e desbloqueado, pois se estiver exibe uma notificação, senão inicia uma `Activity`. Existe algum método ou classe para verificar isso e me dar um retorno?

Answer (score 1):

Tente o KeyguardManager:

```
KeyguardManager myKM = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
if( myKM.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode()) {
 //it is locked
} else {
 //it is not locked
}
```

Fonte:   https://stackoverflow.com/a/8668648/194717

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente, Obrigado!